# Error linking with GCC 4.3.2 on RHEL 5.3 and libstdc++.so. Any GCC gurus?

Tags: c++, linux, gcc, linker, g++

Trying to use the RHEL5.3 GCC 4.3.2 compiler to build my software on that platform.  I get the following error no matter what I try when compiling with -O2, but it builds fine without optimization.  Any ideas?

```
/usr/bin/ld: myapp: hidden symbol `void std::__ostream_fill<char, std::char_traits<char> >(std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> >&, long)' isn't defined
/usr/bin/ld: final link failed: Nonrepresentable section on output
```

In RHEL5.3, I am using `/usr/bin/g++43` for compilation and linking.  The correct `libstdc++.so` is found here:

`/usr/lib/gcc/i386-redhat-linux6E/4.3.2/libstdc++.so`

which is a text file containing `INPUT ( -lstdc++_nonshared /usr/lib/libstdc++.so.6 )`.

Wouldn't that mismatch the system `stdlibc++ 4.1` version?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out to be a GCC bug in RHEL 5.3 :-/.  https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=493929.  I sent an email to the maintainer, Jakub Jelinek, who said that RHEL 5.4 (which is due out soon) will have a fix and also will bump to GCC 4.4.

A workaround is to use -fno-inline, but this has some obvious drawbacks.

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be running into [visibility](http://gcc.gnu.org/wiki/Visibility) issues -- can we see your full command line?

For example, what [`-fvisibility-inlines-hidden`](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.4.0/gcc/C_002b_002b-Dialect-Options.html#index-fvisibility_002dinlines_002dhidden-153) does may change at different optimization levels because GCC decides to inline different things.

Comment: For a component:
/usr/bin/g++43 -c -pipe -Wextra -Wcast-qual -Wno-long-long -m32 -O2 -Wall -W -D_REENTRANT -DQT_GUI_LIB -DQT_CORE_LIB -DQT_SHARED -D_REENTRANT -D_GNU_SOURCE -DQT_NO_DEBUG -DQT_WEBKIT_LIB [various includes, etc]

For the link:
/usr/bin/g++43 -Wl,-O1 -Wl,-rpath,/home/hudson/qt4/lib -o myapp [... a ton of .o files] [various static and shared libraries]

It is a qmake/qt 4.5 project

Comment: Well, I'd have preferred it if you had made that an edit to the question instead of a comment, but oh well :)  Hmm, so it's not quite obvious from this; I'll have to try to find a small test case to reproduce this.

Comment: I was able to reproduce this with the latest Gnucap snapshot (http://www.gnucap.org/devel) -- probably RHEL 5.3 GCC specific
I set CC=/usr/bin/gcc43 CXX=/usr/bin/g++43 LINK=/usr/bin/g++43,
then ran configure and make.  Same error

Answer (score 0):

It only happens with optimization.  Does that give a clue?